# verifyonly error message

Tags: sql, sql-server

I use following sql statement

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = 'F:\testBackup\test_2013-01-18.BAK'
GO
```

I get this error while doing so:

```
Attempting to restore this backup may encounter storage space problems. Subsequent messages will provide details.
The path specified by "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test.mdf" 
is not in a valid directory.
Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_log.ldf" 
failed with the operating system error 3(failed to retrieve text for this error. Reason: 15100).
Msg 3189, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Damage to the backup set was detected.
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
RESTORE VERIFYONLY
   FROM DISK = 'F:\testBackup\test_2013-01-18.BAK'
   WITH NORECOVERY, 
      MOVE 'test_Data'  
          TO '<YourPath>\test.mdf', 
      MOVE 'test_Log' 
          TO '<YourPath>\test_log.ldf';
```

And you can check [MSDN site](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188902.aspx) to further advices.